# How to handle background (app closed/phone sleeping) notifications using Expo?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, expo

In expos's [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo/?redirected), the background notifications are listed under limitations, but also stated, that its work in progress.

There is no trace on the Expos's [roadmap](https://expo.canny.io/) about this though.

Do you know if this has already been finished and not documented or if its WIP in which case, when is the expected realease date?

Until then, do you have any workarounds for the limitation.

**The problem is** simple: client needs to receive a noticeable notification (e.g a call like audio) even when the phone is sleeping/app closed.

Cheers.

Comment: did you ever get anything working for your use case? I have a similar problem Im trying to solve and working with Expo notifications and all the various issues around it is driving me insane :(

Comment: @andymccullough no, this issue hasn't been solved yet. You can't execute code when the app is not currently running or the user interacts with the notification (e.g clicks on the notification). more here https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/handle-push-notifications-in-the-background

Answer (score 0):

Sending push notifications is done from your server so you are totally free in sending them whenever you want and schedule jobs to take care of it.

However you won't be able to handle the receiving of the notification on the client if the app is backgrounded and the user has not selected the notification. According to expo documentation:

You cannot handle push notifications in the background. This is a work in progress.

But if the app is in foreground or the user has selected the notification, then a notification will be passed to the listener in your app.

Comment: Hi, yes thank you. That's also what I mentioned in the question but do you know if there is any timeline on when the feature will be finished as its WIP?